# Tiny editor is not getting post value

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, iframe, rich-text-editor

Here is the code i am using

```
<textarea name="tinyeditor" id="tinyeditor" style="width: 800px; height: 500px"></textarea>
<script>
   var editor = new TINY.editor.edit('editor', {
    id: 'tinyeditor',
    width: 750,
    height: 350,
    cssclass: 'tinyeditor',
    controlclass: 'tinyeditor-control',
    rowclass: 'tinyeditor-header',
    dividerclass: 'tinyeditor-divider',
    controls: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikethrough', '|', 'subscript', 'superscript', '|',
        'orderedlist', 'unorderedlist', '|', 'outdent', 'indent', '|', 'leftalign',
        'centeralign', 'rightalign', 'blockjustify', '|', 'unformat', '|', 'undo', 'redo', 'n',
         'image', 'hr', 'link', 'unlink', '|', 'print'],
    footer: true,
    fonts: ['Verdana','Arial','Georgia','Trebuchet MS'],
    xhtml: true,        
    bodyid: 'editor',
    footerclass: 'tinyeditor-footer',
    toggle: {text: 'source', activetext: 'wysiwyg', cssclass: 'toggle'},
    resize: {cssclass: 'resize'}
   });
</script>
```

My post output is coming like this

```
Array ( [tinyeditor] => [templatename] => test [content] => [textedito] => [Submit_x] => 48 [Submit_y] => 14 )
```

if i remove `id="tinyeditor"` from the text area then post value is coming

Comment: Why the codeigniter-2 and codeigniter-url tags?

Comment: I am implementing in codeigniter thats why !!!!!!!!,Pls help me

Comment: Most likely you aren't properly moving the tinyeditor value to the original textarea before posting. **Read the documentation for tinyeditor.**

Comment: could you post a link to the documentation of it? besides the comments in the code, and the short readme, I can't find a documentation page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to post the data from editor with JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ $(".submit").click(function(){ editor.post(); }); });
```

Where `.submit` is class of submit button

Answer (score 0):

easy way :

Paste your script :

var **editor** = new TINY.editor.edit('editor', {
    id: 'tinyeditor',
    etc.....

on the button form

input type="submit" value="Envoyer" **onClick="editor.post();**"

et voilà