# empty textarea when using tinyEditor and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I use TinyEditor as wysiwyg Editor.
Without using the Editor everything works fine when i submit the php page and I get the text from the TextArea.

```
<textarea name="ARTICLE" id="ARTICLE"><?php echo $entry->text; ?></textarea>

<script>
    var editor = new TINY.editor.edit('editor', {
        id: 'ARTICLE',
        width: 800,
        height: 500,
        cssclass: 'tinyeditor',
        controlclass: 'tinyeditor-control',
        rowclass: 'tinyeditor-header',
        dividerclass: 'tinyeditor-divider',
        controls: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikethrough', '|', 'subscript', 'superscript', '|',
            'orderedlist', 'unorderedlist', '|', 'outdent', 'indent', '|', 'leftalign',
            'centeralign', 'rightalign', 'blockjustify', '|', 'unformat', '|', 'undo', 'redo', 'n',
             'style', '|',  'hr', 'link', 'unlink'],
        footer: false
    });
    </script>
```

When I'm using the Editor i allways get an empty area when the page is submitted.
Before I submit the page I do:

`editor.post();
alert(document.getElementById('ARTICLE').value);
e("entry_edit").submit();`

I alert the value of the textarea before submitting it and there I get all the text in it.

Is there a special way i have to format the text before it can be submitted?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tiny editor is not getting post value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17841262/tiny-editor-is-not-getting-post-value)

Comment: @andrew it's not a duplicate question